# Decompiling a Bin File Inside the SWF file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, decompiling

I decompiled a swf file using JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler v.10.0.0 , When i decompile the swf file I only see 2 scripts:

1. AppLoader
2. $gamename-web_sec$aba37a......

In the binaryData folder, there's a thing named:

1. DefineBinaryData(1:gamename-web_sec$aba37a........

Here's the tree of the decompiled swf:

1. gamename.swf

   - Headers
   - BinaryData

     - DefineBinaryData(1:gamename-websec$aba37a...
   - Frames
   - Scripts

     - AppLoader
     - $gamename-web_sec$aba37a...

inside the appLoader, here's the script:

```
package
{
   import flash.display.Loader;
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
   import flash.system.LoaderContext;
   import flash.utils.ByteArray;
   public class AppLoader extends Sprite
   {
      private var content:Class;
      public function AppLoader()
      {
         content = §gamename-web_sec$aba37a95a98fb59f905d8915dbd77871-2007405621§;
         super();
         var loader:Loader = new Loader();
         addChild(loader);
         var ba:ByteArray = new content();
         var bamod:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         bamod.writeBytes(ba,1,ba.length - 1);
         loader.loadBytes(bamod,new LoaderContext(false,new ApplicationDomain()));
      }
   }
}
```

$gamename-web_sec$aba37a... actionscript:

```
package
{
   import flash.utils.ByteArray;  
   public class §gamename-web_sec$aba37a95a98fb59f905d8915dbd77871-2007405621§ extends ByteArray
   {
      public function §chitchatcity-web_sec$aba37a95a98fb59f905d8915dbd77871-2007405621§()
      {
         super();
      }
   }
}
```

I see that It's loading the swf game with that BinaryData. When i try to export the bin file and try to load it again using JPEXS Flash Decompiler again. This what it shows,

1. [2744232]

   - header
   - shapes
   - sprites
   - binaryData

     - DefineBinaryData (51763)
     - DefineBinaryData (11730)
   - frames
   - others

     - ErrorTag
     - Unknown (ID=377)
     - Unknown (ID=909)
     - Unknown (ID=544)
     - ...
     - Unknown (ID=879)
     - ErrorTag
     - Unknown (ID=777)
     - ....
   - scripts

     - frame1

       - DoAction

It show's so many unknown objects in others folder.

Do P-code source: (because  the actionscript source is blank)

```
Jump loc0005
loc0005:
```

Do you guys have an idea how will i able to decompile the swf file? I have a permission of the owner, and he wants me to decompile it, so we can better secure the game more.

Comment: Just a guess, the inner file is compressed and properly obfuscated prior to that. If I were the one devising the protection, I would also make sure the inner file would not run if unpacked in the wrong environment.

Comment: @Organis In the previous version of the swf file, i was able to decompile it but some scripts are named $obfs55, $obs?? something like that but still readable so i stil able to edit the game. Then this is the next update.

Comment: Renaming identifiers is the one obfuscation method, but **not** the only one. The next level is messing with ABC-bytecode so that it executes in the same way as non-obfuscated one, yet is re-organized in the way normal compilers would never produce. The catch is that it is quite easy to automate such an obfuscation (even with randomization of output) while it takes a professional person to unwind it, a lot of time, and tools that would work with raw ABC-code, because decompilers fail to work anything out of it (well, that's **the** point).

Comment: @Organis will you help me to try to decompile the swf? I'll send you the link of the swf

Comment: No, way too much of a trouble. I know how it works because I coded an obfuscator of my own back in 2006 (I think) for AS1/AS2 apps. As I told above, it takes a blink to protect the code, and hours (or even days) to reverse-engineer it (you can try free demo mode with http://www.kindi.com/ and see for yourself). Once SWF code is properly obfuscated it is faster to write your own app of the same functionality than to decompile the protection. Cool, right?

Comment: @Organis Actually, the obfuscated things are fine with me as long as I can properly decompile the Bin file loaded in the swf game, because I believe that bin file is a swf file.